# Strip and ignore decimals in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

How can I simple delete everything after a decimal place including the decimal so I am left with a whole number?

I.e. `325.6899` needs to be `325` with no rounding.

Ideally I'd like a function that does this but I don't know of any in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply do

```
parseInt(325.6899);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Math.floor`:

```
var foo = Math.floor(325.689);
console.log(foo); // = 325
```

Answer (score 0):

Another different answer

```
var foo = 325.689;
console.log(Number(foo.toString().split(".")[0])); // = 325
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p0v5f7fL/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another;

```
var result = 325.689 - 325.689 % 1;
```

Probably not faster than floor nor better but it works.